# What is the layout system?

Tags: ios, swift, layout, swiftui

In UIKit we used the autolayout system. What layout system does SwiftUI use?

How does it layout the `UIView` in the canvas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use special **Layout Views** like different Stacks and Spacer.
In addition, you can use any **Layout Modifiers**.
To see all of them you can tap new "Library" Button

[image]

Than you can see them:

[image]
[image]

To use one - you should drag&drop one into you code editor, and it will paste corresponding code.

You also can just type it in code editor, of course.

And see more in  [View Layout and Presentation | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view_layout_and_presentation)